# How connect to internal Jira instance via AWS lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, python-jira

I'm trying connect to internal Jira instance use my AWS lambda function. The lambda cannot connect to this web-resource because VPN is required. (all work properly on my local machine under VPN connection).

Please any suggestion regarding this issue ?

Comment: Could you please clarify where the JIRA instance is located? Are you saying that it is in a corporate network, outside of AWS? Is it publicly accessible from the Internet? Do you have an existing connection from the corporate network to AWS (eg via VPN or Direct Connect)?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is an AWS Direct Connect connection between an Amazon VPC and your corporate network, the AWS Lambda function can be configured to connect to the VPC.

The Lambda function can then connect to the JIRA instance on the corporate network by using the **private IP address** of the JIRA instance.

You might be able to configure the VPC to defer to your corporate DNS server to resolve the DNS Name into the IP address, but I would recommend you start by using the private IP address itself to ensure that connectivity is working.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to use SQS messaging.

- Define a message format
- From your lambda function, publish a message when you want to query something
- Have an app/worker running inside your network, which is listening to your SQS queue.
- Your app/worker receives that message and can query to your Jira instance.
- When the result is ready, your app/worker can publish it on other SQS queue
- You can receive the message in another lambda function, or If you want to receive the response in a same lambda function, you can poll for messages and wait till you get your desired message.
- If you have multiple such lambda functions, or many requests going on. You can put a request-id in messages. So, when receiving a message, you can come to know which is your desired message and delete that one only.